# How to properly use String.format with 2 different incoming array sources?

Tags: java, arrays, string

i wish to know the best way to use String.format in this case...

```
String names[] = new String[10];
int idNumber[] = new int[10];
String list = "";

for( byte pos = 0; pos < idNumber.length; pos++){
names[pos] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name...");
idNumber[pos] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enther the ID number..."));
list += ("Name: " + names[pos] + "ID: " + idNumber + "\n");
}
JOptionPane.showMessagedialog(null, list);
```

I wish to use the String.format to change the output of "list"

from:

```
 Name: John Wilson ID: 56
 Name: Edward Sinclair ID: 60
 Name: Bob Stuart ID: 77
```

to:

```
 Name: John Wilson     ID: 56
 Name: Edward Sinclair ID: 60
 Name: Bob Stuart      ID: 77
```

how do i properly use the %-10s... %-5s... in this case ? im a little lost here... thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no difference between your from and to examples?  Also, on a side note, use StringBuilder instead of concatenating to a string via +=.

Comment: You've declared `idNumber` as an array yet you're using it as an integer!

Comment: @vulcan: the difference is the whitespace

Comment: sorry Eric i will fix this, thanks

Comment: Missed one, in the string concatenation line

Comment: @Eric He edited it; they were the same in the initial question.

Comment: @vulcan: no, I did. It was a markdown problem.

Comment: @Vulcan Since Java 1.5 String + String and StringBuilder.append(String) both get compiled to the same bytecode so his method is fine. http://caprazzi.net/posts/java-bytecode-string-concatenation-and-stringbuilder/

Comment: @MrLore In appending just one string to another, using `+` is no different than using a StringBuilder, correct.  However, the OP is appending 10 strings, so using a StringBuilder actually *is* more efficient.  The article you linked mentions this concept as well.

Comment: Eric, i used you example, and its not printing idNumber vallues... and without "Name: " and "ID: ", its just printing out the names, without scpace between... i need to print out in 1 message all the names and all the IDs correctly aligned to the left margin independent of the number of characters...

Comment: You should have commented that on my answer. I don't see how it can possibly not be printing the heading text.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see what you were having problems with using string.format. Did you actually try it?

```
list += ("Name: %20s ID: %02d\n").format(names[pos], idNumber[pos]);
```

As mentioned, it would be more efficient to have:

```
StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
```

And then replace `list += ...` with `list.append(...)`

Comment: I recommend using StringBuilder instead of using `+=` to append one string to another.  It improves efficiency to do so.